# How to re-run recorded pivot table macro?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I recorded a macro to get pivot table from one data source, and assigned the code to a button.

The code works when I execute the macro for the first time

When I re-run the macro for the second time, it is giving some run time error. I know the reason that there is already a table present in the table destination range. How do I make my macro in such a way that the button works only once or only if the data changes in the source data sheet?

sample code

```
Sub pivotexample()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Sheets("pivot_view").Select
    For Each Pt In Sheets("pivot_view").PivotTables
        Sheets("pivot_view").Range(PT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next PT

    Sheets("result").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "result!R1C1:R1048576C26", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="pivot_view!R8C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("pivot_view").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("week_name")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1

        'code for all the pivot table fields.

    End With

    Set pt = Worksheets("pivot_view").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    Range("A8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range("A8:I8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Range("A9").Offset(pt.TableRange1.Rows.Count, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("task_queue_name")  'getting error in this line, when i run the code for once, it is working fine, the name of the pivotTable2 would be pivotTable2 only, but when i remove the old pivot tables using the loop you have suggested and run that for the second time, the name of the second pivot table is getting changed.
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
end sub
```

Comment: please post you code

Comment: Hi @andreas Hofmann, thank you, I just posted the sample code, could you check once?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain more about your Problem, because your question consists actually of multiple questions, such as:

- How to remove the run time error?
- How to make my macro run only once?
- How to check if the data in a Range has changed?

I interpreted your question as if you simply want the error gone.
Threfore  you could simply delete the old table and replace it with the new one.

Like this:

```
Sub test()

Sheets("result").Select    'result is source data sheet
Cells.Select
Sheets("pivot_view").Select  'pivot_view is my destination sheet where my pivot table should be placed

'============
'delete previous pivot table, to allow a new pivot table to get created in the same place
'code snippet source https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/518955-vba-delete-pivot-table.html
'code snippet autor Zack Barresse
For Each PT In Sheets("pivot_view").PivotTables
    If PT.name = "PivotTable1" then Sheets("pivot_view").Range(PT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next PT
'============

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "result!R1C1:R1048576C26", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="pivot_view!R8C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("pivot_view").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("week_name")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("team_manager")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "vertical_or_sub_initiative")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
End With
End Sub
```

The current code will delete ALL Pivot tables on sheet "pivot_view". If you want to only create and delete specific ones try this:

```
Sub recreate_pivot()
    Call delete_pvt("pivot_view", "PivotTable1")
    Call test("result", "pivot_view", "PivotTable1", "A1:C3", "A8")

    Call delete_pvt("pivot_view", "PivotTable2")
    Call test("result", "pivot_view", "PivotTable2", "A1:C3", "D8")

End Sub


Sub delete_pvt(pvt_sheet As String, pvt_name As String)

'============
'delete previous pivot table, to allow a new pivot table to get created in the same place
'code snippet source https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/518955-vba-delete-pivot-table.html
'code snippet autor Zack Barresse
'============

For Each PT In Sheets(pvt_sheet).PivotTables
    If PT.Name = pvt_name Then Sheets(pvt_sheet).Range(PT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next PT

End Sub

Sub test(source_sheet As String, pvt_sheet As String, pvt_name As String, source_rng As String, dest_rng_str As String)

Dim dest_rng As Range
Set dest_rng = Sheets(pvt_sheet).Range(dest_rng_str)

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    source_sheet & "!" & source_rng).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=dest_rng, TableName:=pvt_name
Sheets(pvt_sheet).Select

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvt_name).PivotFields("week_name")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvt_name).PivotFields("team_manager")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvt_name).PivotFields( _
    "vertical_or_sub_initiative")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you understood what I wanted, and you did it, it worked great. Can you check my other doubt also?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759977/vba-code-for-slicers-to-connect-two-pivot-tables

Comment: The loop you have suggested, works great when there is only one pivot table, but it's not working when there're two pivot tables, i'm always getting error at the second pivot table, the name of the first pivot table is being constant i.e., PivotTable1, but the second pivot table name is getting changed every time i run the code to pivotTable2,pivotTable3,PivotTable4.. fyi, when i created the macro, i first created one pivot table and i copied the first pivottable and pasted in the same sheet and added another field to it, i will post the code in the question, could you check it once?

Comment: See Edit in Answer @srikanth v, glad I could help. Please be more specific. What exactly happens? And what should happen but does not?

Comment: I want to delete both the pivot tables, I'll explain from start, I created a macro which gives two pivot tables from one data source, when I first run the code, I'm getting both the pivot tables, now if I click the run button again both the old pivot tables should go away and replace it with the new ones, but it's not happening, if I press f8 button and checking the code, I'm getting the first pivot table and I'm getting the error at the second pivot table, because I don't know why, the first pivot table name is being the same (pivotTable1), but the name of second PT is changing from pt2, pt3.

Comment: Ok, understood. Is there a reason you want to create he Pivot tables again? Because you coudl simply write a macro which updates the source data of both pivot tables.

Comment: Reason is, I know that I should be executing the program for only once, but what if I gave the macro to someone else, who doesn't how it works, so if he executes the macro, for the first it will give both the pivot tables and for the second time he runs it again by pressing the button assigned with macro, he will get the error, that's why I want to remove both the pivot tables and replace it with the new ones.

Comment: See the second code, I adjusted it. Hope it helps, please marka s answer if it does. Best wishes.

Comment: Hello Andreas Hofmann, sorry for the late reply, I made few changes in my code (earlier I created one pivot table and copied that PT and pasted down and added one extra field to the new PT), now I created both separately, and the loop you have suggested (For Each Pt In Sheets("pivot_view").PivotTables Sheets("pivot_view").Range(PT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp Next PT) working great, thank you so much, can you check my other query also, I want to create a slicer to join this two pivot tables, so that I don't need to change both pts filters manually, code is same.